# What sets my Java Virtual Machine?

Tags: macos, java

I'm not understanding how my Java environment is getting set up.  If I have multiple versions of Java installed how does the correct version get selected when I start a Java dependent application?

I have both Apple's original 1.6 version of Java and Sun's more recent 1.8 installed.

If I type `java -version` I get

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)`
```

`ls -l /usr/bin/java` produces `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    74 Jun 16   2014 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java` where `Current` is pointed at Apple's 1.6 Java install.

Comment: Looks like your `/usr/bin/java` is still Java 6 but in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` the Java 8 installer has appended its path in front of the original one - so that when you just do `java` by default it picks up the Java 8 version.

Comment: `which java` produces `/usr/bin/java` so I wouldn't think it would be the path variable that's the issue.  I've also heard that the shell is irrelevant to the environment in which applications are launched, which is why my browsers all successfully use Sun's 1.8 install while my path is still pointed at the old Apple version.

Comment: @Keith /usr/bin/java is not used by web java that is controlled by the Java control panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java executables in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java  are not the executables that just run the java compiler etc. They are wrappers that use /usr/libexec/java_home to find the executables.

Apple's Java 6 is in /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

Run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to see all the Java VMs you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

In your current terminal session you can select the JVM using
`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` see `java_home --help` for more options.

For GUI applications you should set JAVA_HOME as an environment variable.  Setting Environment variables in Mac OS is explained in [Environment variables in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x) on StackOverflow. Be aware that `~/.launchd.conf` is deprecated: `man launchd.con`on Yosemite

> ...launchd.conf is no longer respected by the system. ...

Comment: I wish I could select more than one answer because yours was also helpful.  Unfortunately @Mark's explanation that the executables are really wrappers was the direct answer to my question.  The environment variables stuff you pointed to is also really helpful.  Thank you.